# Cauchy-Schwarz-like Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, summation, convex-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sums-of-squares

Let $a_i, b_i >0$ for all $n$ and $0 \le \lambda  \le 1$

Is the following result true for all $n$?

$$ \sum^n_{i=0} a^\lambda_i b^{1-\lambda}_i \le 
\left( \sum^n_{i=0} a_i \right) ^\lambda 
\left( \sum^n_{i=0} b_i\right) ^{1-\lambda} $$

This is trivial for $n=1$, but I am getting stuck on the inductive step.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure) could be useful

Comment: I think you should put that as an answer!

Comment: @podiki So we have Holder's inequality which is in the next comment 

Assume $p \text { and } q \in (1, \infty) \text { with } 1 / p+1 / q=1$

In the case of the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, when the set $S$ is $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with the counting measure, Holder's inequality gives (why?):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|x_{k} y_{k}\right| \leq\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|x_{k}\right|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|y_{k}\right|^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \text { for all }\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right),\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} 
$$

Comment: Are you asking 1. Why the equation in your comment follows from Holder's inequality? 2. How to prove Holder's inequality? Or 3. How to see your equation from the one in your comment?

Comment: I was going to continue in another comment. I have two questions, one is indeed why the equation in my comment follows from Holder (I am not well-versed in this counting measure concept). The second is why the "practical version" follows from the equation in my comment.

The practical form: for any $(r, s) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$:
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|x_{k}\right|^{r}\left|y_{k}\right|^{s}\right)^{r+s} \leq\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|x_{k}\right|^{r+s}\right)^{r}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|y_{k}\right|^{r+s}\right)^{s}
$$

Comment: An answer to the first question probably requires at least a bit of measure theory. The second is easier. Let $1/p = r/(s+r)$ and $1/q=s/(s+r)$ (note that $1/p+1/q=1$) and then replace $\vert x_k\vert\mapsto\vert x_k\vert^r$ and $\vert y_k\vert\mapsto\vert y_k\vert^ s$ and then raise the whole thing to the $r+s$ power noting that $t^{r+s}$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I'm happy with measure theory @podiki, any light that you can shed? Here is the statement of Holder's from Wikipedia for everyone's reference:

Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $p, q \in[1, \infty]$ with $1 / p+1 / q=1$. Then for all measurable real- or complex-valued functions $f$ and $g$ on $S$, $\|f g\|_{1} \leq\|f\|_{p}\|g\|_{q}$

Comment: For the counting measure on the set $S=\{1,\dots,n\}$ then $\mu(A)=k$ if $A$ contains $k$ elements. A function on $S$ is just a finite sequence, and an integral is just the sum of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward from Hölder’s inequality in Euclidean spaces:

$$\|a\cdot b\|_1 \leq \|a\|_p \|b\|_q$$ for any $p,q\in (1,\infty) : 1/p+1/q=1 $, and for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $ 1/p = \lambda $ and $1/q = 1 - \lambda $ when $ \lambda \in (0,1)$ since the other case when $\lambda = 0$ or $1$ is trivial. Then let $a= \tilde{a}^\lambda, b=  \tilde{b}^{(1-\lambda)}$ and we are done

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** It is easy (e.g., by taking the derivative) to show that $x^\lambda \le \lambda x + 1 - \lambda \ \forall x > 0$.

**Step 2:** Replacing $x$ in Step 1 with $\frac{x}{y}$ we obtain $x^\lambda y^{1-\lambda} \le \lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y \quad \forall x,y > 0.$

**Step 3:** Let $A = \sum_i a_i, B = \sum_i b_i$. Applying the inequality in Step 2 for each $i$ with $x = \frac{a_i}{A},y = \frac{b_i}{B}$. Summing up the resulting $n+1$ inequalities we obtain the result.